# Magento problem accessing image file

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload, image-preview

im having an unusual problem when i try to access a saved file. i am saving an image to the media folder where i have created another floder called customers. the folder is set to 775. when i add an image using php it saves the image correctly to the folder but when i try to access the image using theu url link it doesn't work - i have checked if the image url is correct and it is but i don't know why i am getting a 404 error when i access the image. i have uploaded pictures using php before on this site for the blog section and it works fine and i can see the images correctly but i don't know why when i upload images to the customers folder, the images don't display

Please could someone help

Comment: have you installed the latest security patch recently?

Comment: no i havent installed it - do i need to?

Comment: you should always ;) but there was a change which limited the permissions of new images created so that many shops had the problem that they could not see them anymore in the frontend (and in backend).

Comment: if i do the update will it delete my files - because i have some in the base folder and i don't want them to be removed.

Comment: i know that i shouldn't have done anything to that folder but its too late to change it

Comment: that depends on how you update. Installing the patch should not delete anything, except you changed a file that the patch patches (then the patch will fail). But Installing the Patch won't likely solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the url you are using to display the image file placed in customer folder of media directory?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the security patch SUPEE-7405? then check this:

Source: http://my.aspirationhosting.com/knowledgebase/1482/Image-Upload-Issue-with-Magento-1923-or-SUPEE-7405.html

> **Magento Community Edition 1.9.2.3** and the **Security Patch SUPEE-7405** introduced a new bug with image uploading which resulted in incorrect file permissions for newly uploaded images. 
> If you have uploaded any images which are not showing up, the first thing to do is to [set the correct file permissions](http://my.aspirationhosting.com/knowledgebase/1479/How-do-I-set-the-correct-file-permissions-for-Magento.html) for your files and databases. 
> To permanently resolve the problem, you will need to modify a file within Magento. 
> **Important Note:** This is a manual hack which will be overwritten during a Magento upgrade. 
> Open up the following file:-
>
> ```
> lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
> ```
>
> Look for this line:-
>
> ```
> chmod($destinationFile, 0640);
> ```
>
> Replace it with this line:-
>
> ```
> chmod($destinationFile, 0644);
> ```
>
> Look for this line:-
>
> ```
> chmod($destinationFile, 0750);
> ```
>
> Replace it with this line:-
>
> ```
> chmod($destinationFile, 0755);
> ```
>
> Save the file and the next image uploaded should load properly.